# Html on click change property; reclick back to original state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I am trying to change the properties of a span element such as its borders and background colour when I click it. I also want to reset the element properties to what they used to be, when it is clicked again. However I am not being able to do it properly. I accept any type of solutions, including Jquery. Actually my code is currently Jquery:

```
$('.clickable_span').click(function() {

  if($(this).attr('border') == undefined || $(this).attr('border') == false) {

    $(this).css('background', 'white');
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');

  }

  else if($(this).attr('border') == true) {

       $(this).css('background', 'dimgrey');
       $(this).css('border', 'none');

  }

});
```

It keeps entering the first if statement (I console.logged) so it changes the aspect of the element but doesn't reset it back to the original state. What is wrong with the code? Why does *$(this).attr('border')* is still equal to undefined after giving that property to the element? (the difference is visible).

Comment: are you sure you want the border attribute, or do you want the css property?  I wasnt sure if you were trying to get the property from within css, etc... or if you were trying something else.  Kinda the first thing that jumps out at me though.

Comment: so you basically want to change the attribute and the first click and reset it if you click twice correct?

Comment: jQuery `css` method sets the inline style of elements, it doesn't add arbitrary attributes to elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A much easier way would be to use `toggleClass()`:

```
.change_css { background: white; border: 1px solid black; }
.original { background: dimgrey; border: none; }

<span class="original">....</span> // start your span with a class
```

then toggle both classes:

```
$('.clickable_span').click(function() {

    $(this).toggleClass("original").toggleClass("change_css");

});
```

As `.original` is removed, `.change_css` is added and vice versa.

jQueryUI's `switchClass()` will also work (click [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/) for docs):

```
$(this).switchClass( "original", "change_css" );
```

Comment: Your answer works like a charm. It was not on my question but when I create more than one span of that kind, some of the spans do not change the class. What should I do when I have more of these spans with the same class and I want to select each of them individually?

Comment: You'll need to add an additional class to the span or creatively use selectors to distinguish them

Answer (score 1):

`.css()` and `.attr()` are not interchangeable. `$(this).css('background')` targets the 'background' style property of the DOM element (i.e. `<div style="background: some_value;">`, while `$(this).attr('background')` targets an attribute *named* 'background' on the element (i.e. `<div background="some_value">`)

Unfortunately you can't just change the `.attr()` checks in the `if` statements to `.css()` because the border css property won't necessarily return `false` or `undefined` (for example if it's set to `'none'`).  A better solution would be to create and toggle a class, as in The One and Only ChemistryBlob's answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can't check border with .attr() as it is css property not html attribute so you can try to add 2 classes with the 2 states you want and toggle them on click.

You can try this snippet:

```js
$('.clickable_span').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('original-state after-click');
});
```

```css
.original-state{
    background: dimgrey;
    border:none;
}
.after-click{
    background: white;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="clickable_span original-state">Click me!</span>
```